# About reference one by one and reader closing

Tags: java

I have two short questions.

Here is the first

```
  //global
  private static final URL ca = Administrator.class.getResource("category.txt");

  //inside some method
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(ca.getFile())));
  br.close():
```

Is this a good practice? I mean I embed `FileReader` as a parameter, so I may not be able to close it. And I suppose java may be smart enough to close it when `br` is closed?

Second:
After I close br, can I use it to reference another `BufferedReader` and instantiate it in the same way with a different file?

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first question is yes. `BufferedReader` is a wrapper for another `Reader` and uses/closes that reader in it's methods so the whole result of calling `BufferedReader.close()` is to close the internal `Reader`. This [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html) explains the wrapping and why it's useful.

The answer to the second question is also yes. In fact you could just assign `br` to new `BufferedReader` without bothering to close the first, but this that would be bad practice. The key here is that you're replacing the field, not reusing the former object. So it's perfectly doable, and safe once you close.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this a good practice? I mean I embed FileReader as a parameter, so I may not be able to close it.

You don't need to close it. Closing the BufferedReader closes it.

> And I suppose java may be smart enough to close it when br is closed?

Yes, see the Javadoc.

> Second: After I close br, can I use it to reference another BufferedReader and instantiate it in the same way with a different file?

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

> And I suppose java may be smart enough to close it when `br` is closed?

Yes. The [`BufferedReader.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#close--) Javadoc says (in part)

> Closes the stream and releases any system resources associated with it.

The `FileReader` is a system resource associated with the `BufferedReader` in your question.

> After I close `br`, can I use it to reference another BufferedReader and instantiate it in the same way with a different file?

Yes. As long as you call `new BufferedReader`.